# SQL Server : how do I find the change in percentage from the date prior?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a table similar to the one below. I'm looking to find the change in percentage from the most recent week to the week prior going back to inception. I'm not entirely sure what the best way to identify what the week prior is with respect to the `ItemID` in order to make the subtraction. I assume I can't get around this without a subquery or creating a `TEMP` table and assigning some sort of rank ID to identify which date is the prior date for this `ItemID`. Any help?

Current table:

```
SalesDate   ItemID  COUNT   TotCount    PERC
----------------------------------------------------
3/11/2017   1       7       755         0.009271523
1/11/2017   1       6       670         0.008955224
12/31/2016  1       5       655         0.007633588
12/17/2016  1       4       635         0.006299213
11/9/2016   1       3       580         0.005172414
10/22/2016  1       2       555         0.003603604
9/21/2016   1       1       510         0.001960784
```

Desired table with newest `PERC` minus prior date `PERC` (ie 3/11/2017 PERC minus 1/11/2017 PERC will equal 0.000316299):

```
SalesDate   ItemID  COUNT   TotCount    PERC         change
----------------------------------------------------------------
3/11/2017   1       7       755         0.009271523  0.000316299
1/11/2017   1       6       670         0.008955224  0.001321636
12/31/2016  1       5       655         0.007633588  0.001334375
12/17/2016  1       4       635         0.006299213  0.001126799
11/9/2016   1       3       580         0.005172414  0.00156881
10/22/2016  1       2       555         0.003603604  0.001642819
9/21/2016   1       1       510         0.001960784  0.001960784
```

Edit: to be clear, I have multiple `ItemID`'s in this table so the subquery would need to factor in that the date prior is specific to the `ItemID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `lag()`.  I would write this as:

```
select t.*,
       (perc - lag(perc) over (partition by itemId order by SalesDate)) as diff
from t;
```

This would return `NULL` for the last row.  You can fix that by doing:

```
select t.*,
       (perc - lag(perc, 1, 0) over (partition by itemId order by SalesDate)) as diff
from t;
```